# NullPointer Exception in "org.drools.core.spi.Tuple.getFactHandle()"

Tags: java, drools, kie

We've recently attempted to upgrade our rules engine to Spring 2.6 and java 17. During that process we also bumped our drools bom version to `7.66.0.Final`.

In our trials, we noticed that rules seem to execute fine for the first 5 or 6 executions, then throw the following exception:

```
org.drools.mvel.ConstraintEvaluationException: Error evaluating constraint 'RuleUtils.evaluateCoverageClassCondition($empStatusCodesNotParam, $empStatusCodeValue)' in 
    at org.drools.mvel.MVELConstraint.evaluate(MVELConstraint.java:286)
    at org.drools.mvel.MVELConstraint.isAllowedCachedLeft(MVELConstraint.java:246)
    at org.drools.core.common.TripleBetaConstraints.isAllowedCachedLeft(TripleBetaConstraints.java:114)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakFromNode.propagate(PhreakFromNode.java:276)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakFromNode.doLeftInserts(PhreakFromNode.java:114)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakFromNode.doNode(PhreakFromNode.java:61)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:399)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:345)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.doRiaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:630)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:553)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:385)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:345)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalStackEntry(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:243)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.outerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:186)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evaluateNetwork(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:139)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.reEvaluateNetwork(RuleExecutor.java:235)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:91)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:869)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:816)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:808)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1343)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1334)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1326)
    at com.accolade.acp.rulesengine.eventhandlers.generic.EventHandler.executeRules(EventHandler.java:177)
    at com.accolade.acp.rulesengine.eventhandlers.generic.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:148)
    at com.accolade.acp.rulesengine.eventhandlers.ClaimEventHandler.handleEvent(ClaimEventHandler.java:42)
    at com.accolade.acp.rulesengine.eventhandlers.ClaimEventHandler.handleEvent(ClaimEventHandler.java:17)
    at com.accolade.eventbus.framework.eventhandlers.AbstractEventHandler.executeHandler(AbstractEventHandler.java:100)
    at com.accolade.eventbus.framework.eventhandlers.AbstractEventHandler.parseMessage(AbstractEventHandler.java:85)
    at com.accolade.eventbus.framework.common.jms.JmsMessageHandler.onMessage(JmsMessageHandler.java:74)
    at com.accolade.boot.autoconfigure.eventbus.wrappers.JmsTimerMessageHandler.onMessage(JmsTimerMessageHandler.java:25)
    at com.accolade.boot.autoconfigure.eventbus.wrappers.JmsTimerMessageHandler$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$70b1fd14.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
    at com.accolade.core.monitoring.annotations.TimerInstrumentLogger.lambda$logAround$0(TimerInstrumentLogger.java:19)
    at com.accolade.core.monitoring.FunctionTimerLogger.timeFunction(FunctionTimerLogger.java:17)
    at com.accolade.core.monitoring.annotations.TimerInstrumentLogger.logAround(TimerInstrumentLogger.java:17)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor572.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at com.accolade.boot.autoconfigure.eventbus.wrappers.JmsTimerMessageHandler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d4f51ab.onMessage(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:761)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:699)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1120)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.drools.core.common.InternalFactHandle.getObject()" because the return value of "org.drools.core.spi.Tuple.getFactHandle()" is null
    at ConditionEvaluator469159a2125247c0a13499d13f5a2c03.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.drools.mvel.MVELConstraint.evaluate(MVELConstraint.java:284)
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

Here's the rule:

```
rule "Base.NewMembershipCoverageV2"
    when
        $configuredRule : ConfiguredRule(StringUtils.equals(ruleId, RuleConsts.RULE_BASE_NEW_MEMBERSHIP_COVERAGE_V2),
            $relationshipParam : RuleUtils.getOptionalParameterValue(parameters, RuleConsts.PARAMETER_RELATIONSHIP_CODE),
            $empStatusCodesNotParam : RuleUtils.getOptionalStringArrayParameter(parameters, RuleConsts.PARAMETER_EMP_STATUS_CODE_NOT),
            $covgStatusNotParam : RuleUtils.getOptionalStringArrayParameter(parameters, RuleConsts.PARAMETER_COVG_STATUS_CODE_NOT),
            $contractTypeParam : RuleUtils.getOptionalParameterValue(parameters, RuleConsts.PARAMETER_CONTRACT_TYPE),
            $contractSubTypeListParam : RuleUtils.getOptionalStringArrayParameter(parameters, RuleConsts.PARAMETER_CONTRACT_SUBTYPE_LIST));
        $configuredRulesFired : RuleFiredWrapper(configuredRuleSet not contains $configuredRule);

        AcpEvent(type.equalsIgnoreCase(RuleConsts.ACP_EVENT_MEMBERSHIP_COVERAGE_CREATE) || type.equalsIgnoreCase(RuleConsts.ACP_EVENT_MEMBERSHIP_COVERAGE_UPDATE));
        $coverage : Coverage(RuleUtils.containsCode(type, "membership"),
                     $idList : identifier)
        exists(
            Coverage(RuleUtils.containsCode(type, "membership"),
                $relationshipParam.isEmpty || (relationship != null &&
                    RuleUtils.containsCode(relationship, String.valueOf($relationshipParam.get))),
                $empStatusCodeValue : RuleUtils.getCoverageClassValue("EMP_STATUS_CD", this),
                RuleUtils.evaluateCoverageClassCondition($empStatusCodesNotParam, coverageClass, $empStatusCodeValue), // <-- THE ERROR LOGS IN THIS FUNCTION
                $covgStatusValue : RuleUtils.getCoverageClassValue("COVG_STATUS_MODIFIER_CD", this),
                RuleUtils.evaluateCoverageClassCondition($covgStatusNotParam, coverageClass, $covgStatusValue),
                $assignedContractIdList : Extractors.getAllRefIds(contract));
            and
            (
                eval($contractTypeParam.isEmpty() && ArrayUtils.isEmpty($contractSubTypeListParam))
                or
                (
                    EmbeddedResources($contractList : resources)
                    and
                    Contract($customerContractIdList : id, Contract.ContractStatus.EXECUTED.equals(status),
                        RuleUtils.isActivePeriod(applies),
                        $contractTypeParam.isEmpty
                            || ($contractTypeParam.isPresent && RuleUtils.containsCode(type, String.valueOf($contractTypeParam.get))),
                        $subTypeList : subType)
                        from $contractList
                    and
                    (
                        eval(ArrayUtils.isEmpty($contractSubTypeListParam))
                        or
                        CodeableConcept($contractSubTypeListParam == null || $contractSubTypeListParam.length == 0 || (this != null && $contractSubTypeListParam != null
                            && Extractors.getFirstCode(this).get memberOf $contractSubTypeListParam))
                            from $subTypeList
                    )
                    and
                    eval(RuleUtils.exactMatch($customerContractIdList.get(), $assignedContractIdList))
                )
            )
        )
    then
        insert(RuleConsts.RULE_BASE_NEW_MEMBERSHIP_COVERAGE_V2);
        Reference $reference = Reference.createLiteralAndLogical(ResourceType.COVERAGE,
                                                RuleUtils.getId($coverage, $idList));
        modify($configuredRulesFired) {
            addConfiguredRule($configuredRule)
        }
        modify($configuredRulesFired) {
            putBasedOn($configuredRule, $reference)
        }
    end
```

And here's the very simple Java check that's throwing the error:

```java
    public static boolean evaluateCoverageClassCondition(String[] paramArray,
                                                         List<Coverage.CoverageClass> coverageClass,
                                                         String value) {
        return ArrayUtils.isEmpty(paramArray) || (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(coverageClass)
                && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(value)
                && !List.of(paramArray).contains(value));
    }
```

Originally we thought it was a memory leak, and it still feels like one; but any rule that calls this function will error out after a few successful executions, but most other rules seem to execute without throwing. We're calling .dispose() in a finally so we're reasonably sure it's getting called after the event. Is there anywhere I should be looking to resolve this issue?

Comment: ... please don't take this the wrong way, but that rule is horrifying.

Comment: @Roddy of the Frozen Peas I don't blame you, a lot of us think the same way. A lot of these rules have been around since we first started using drools many, many years ago. 
I might delete this question since we may have found a solution that's may be unrelated to both drools and our rule (still working to confirm); but I definitely wish there were more best practices on writing good rules, and more stricter IDE tooling around it. The Intellij plugin is never updated, and a lot of our team feel the eclipse tool is also archaic.

Comment: Other than a few bugs in the syntax in the IntelliJ plugin, I've found it not so awful. But for syntax it's generally up to human reviewers to make value judgments. Those `evals` are bad, and really any time you end up having "ors" it's usually indicative that you probably should have two rules, maybe with some inheritance from a common base.

Comment: Great tips, thanks!